# Problem writing to a text input in python's mechanize module

Tags: python, submit, mechanize, textinput

First and foremost, I am writing a python script to automate purchasing of certain domains from dreamhost.com.  I first go to the website's panel where users can do pretty much anything the site has to offer.  Here is the code:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("https://panel.dreamhost.com/index.cgi?tree=domain.registration&")
br.select_form(name="a")
br["username"]="my_username_here"
br["password"]="my_password_here"
br.submit()
```

This code words perfectly and logs me into the panel.  From here, there is a textbox to enter your domain and a multi-select to choose your extension - when this form is submitted, it checks for availability.

I take a similar approach to the success above and perform the following:

```
br.select_form(name="f")
br["Pick Domain Name"] = "domainiwanttobuy"    #textbox
br["tld"] = [extension list]                   #select from dropdown
br.submit()
```

The resulting HTML after this form has been submitted shows that the dropdown changes appropriately, but the text field is blank and I get an error from dreamhost that says, "Error: Please enter a domain name above."

So the input field isn't working - I looked at the corresponding page source HTML and here it is:

```
<input name="fqdn" id="fqdn" class="text reg_domain_input" name="Pick Domain Name" value="mynewdomain" onChange="tradeMarkCheck(this.id)">
```

First of all it's suspect that there are 2 name elements.  I cannot use the name="fqdn" or it says that such a control doesn't exist.  Secondly, I see that a javascript function is called when the value changes.  I'm aware that mechanize cannot handle Javascript, but I don't believe that the function does anything of value.  So, I don't think it's causing the problem.  Here is the corresponding javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function tradeMarkCheck(x) {
    var domain = document.getElementById(x).value;
    var bad = /(dream.*host|host.*dream)/;

    if (bad.test(domain)) {
        alert("NOTE: Domains containing 'DreamHost' in them are not eligible for use with DreamHost Rewards.  Also, please ensure that your site/domain does not dilute or infringe upon the 'DreamHost' trademark (if you have any questions as to whether a use is legal or not, contact us at abuse@dreamhost.com).");
    }
}
</script>
```

I've spent hours debugging this and trying to get a workaround.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked at the site but I strongly suspect that some javascript is doing something that you're not doing with mechanize. The standard answer in these cases is to use [Selenium Webdriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html) to automate a browser (it has a Python API).

Edit:
Selenium Webdriver has HtmlUnit headless browser that supports javascript a little, but it's far from full javascript support. [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/) might be able to help you out, it's a headless version of Webkit.

Comment: The only problem is I cannot have the process visible to the user and as far as I'm aware, there's no way to hide the browser from the user with selenium right?

Comment: I ended up going with Selenium - the documentation for Python was horrible but everything ran correctly once you figured out the syntax.  Thanks for your help.